# How to evaluate $\lim \limits_{v \to c^-} \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac {v^2}{c^2}}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to know how to determine the limit of the following expression and what does it mean for the velocity of an object. Thanks in advance!

$$\lim \limits_{v \to c^-} \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac {v^2}{c^2}}}$$

$v$ is approaching $c$ from the left. It can easily be missed in the display. It clearly implies an object cannot move faster than light and I'm wondering what would the limit of the expression be.

This question was posed to us by our Calculus teacher and sure enough it made itself present on the test. What it specifically asked us was to:

1) Determine the limit.
2) Interpret the result and write down what we inferred from it.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to compute this limit? Is there any particular reason you would like to know what it is? If so, these are things you generally should include in your question. As a first step, note that the denominator seems to approach zero.

Comment: The limit is $\infty$ and the interpretation is that the mass tends to $\infty$, if the velocity $v$ tends to $c$

Comment: This is the effective mass of an object that might be in motion. It grows with velocity (albeit slowly for $v \ll c$), which tells us that it is harder and harder to accelerate an object moving near the speed of light.

Comment: From this formula you can derive that a mass cannot be accelerated to $c$

Comment: The 2 in the root symbol is not wrong , but it feels unpro. Just saying. Also this somewhat physics ...

Comment: @MichaelHardy. No, the limit when $v \to 0$ is $m_0$. The asymptotic behaviour to order $v^2$ is $m_0 + \frac12 mv^2 / c^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator is a constant and the denominator goes to zero, so the limit is $+\infty$.  You can make the expression as large as you want by taking $v$ close enough to $c$